# How can I set the property of the model when calling its view from the page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

I have an index page, that needs to display the content of my partial view.

```
@(Html.Partial("_PartialView", new PartialModel { ID = int.Parse(Html.Raw(Model.ModelA.Report.ID).ToString()) }))
```

Partial view has a model called `PartialModel` with a property called `ID`

Model property: `public int ID { get; set; }`

Here, I'm trying to set the property of my `PartialModel` to ID value from the `ModelA`, bound to the Index view.

When doing that I'm getting the following error:

> System.Web.HttpParseException: 'The explicit expression block is
>   missing a closing ")" character.  Make sure you have a matching ")"
>   character for all the "(" characters within this block, and that none
>   of the ")" characters are being interpreted as markup.'

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

maybe just try

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", new PartialModel { ID = Model.ModelA.Report.ID })
```